How to infer the memory bandwidth for a python application?
I'm training a reinforcement learning workload in python3.8, I managed to improve the end-to-end time by approximately 20%. Subsequently, I utilized Intel Vtune to measure memory bandwidth and discovered that the baseline average DRAM bandwidth is 6.7 GB/sec, whereas the optimized bandwidth is approximately 3.69 GB/sec.
Command to run: vtune -collect hpc-performance -knob collect-memory-bandwidth=true -knob dram-bandwidth-limits=true python file.py
Sample output:
Bandwidth Utilization
    Bandwidth Domain  Platform Maximum  Observed Maximum  Average  % of Elapsed Time with High BW Utilization(%)
    ----------------  ----------------  ----------------  -------  ---------------------------------------------
    DRAM, GB/sec      35                          17.000    3.696                                           0.0%

In terms of optimization, rather than sampling from a large replay buffer (this is in memory) of 2 million entries, I opted to sample from a smaller pool of 100K entries. These entries were then stored in a cache utilizing DRAM space. This optimization improved the locality by sampling batches of entries from a more compact buffer. This sampling process was carried out over 500K time steps.
Can anyone help me comprehend how the memory bandwidth results correlate with the training time?
Thanks

If we don't know the nature of the optimizations applied (and exactly where/how they moved the bottlenecks around), how do you expect anyone to say?

...if your optimizations simply reduced the total amount of CPU-bound work to be done, f/e, then it's not surprising to see the effort feeding the CPU drop as other components of the task to be performed become more prominant by comparison. But that's just spitballing -- we'd need far, far more details to say anything usefully authoritative.

Hi, sorry about that; I just added the optimization process. Please let me know if you need any other details.

Hmm. If you run the numbers on L2 and L3 cache utilization, are you seeing them go up? (Don't need to go to DRAM if data is small enough to sit closer to the CPU).

I haven't run for the cache utilization yet. But, the IPC goes up by almost 20%. I measure the LLC loads, and they correlate with the time improvement.
